# Prove: If $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$, then $A - D \subseteq B- C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that for every four sets A, B, C and D,
if $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$, then $A - D \subseteq B- C$

Assume $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$

Since $A - D \subseteq B- C$ then $x \in A-D$ and $x \in C-B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin D$ and $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$. Then we have $A \subseteq B$

Now I'm stuck. $x \notin C$ and $x \notin D$ $\equiv$ $\emptyset \in C$ and $\emptyset \in D$. Then we have $C \subseteq D$.

---

For clarification purposes, since there is no element in set C and set D, they are the empty set and we can say that $C \subseteq D$

Is this right? Open to any other approach. Thanks!

### Correction

Assume $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$

Let $x \in A - D $. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin D$.

Since $x \in A$ and  $A \subseteq B$. Then $x \in B$.

And since $x \notin D$ and $C \subseteq D$ then $x \notin C$

Hence, $A - D \subseteq B- C$

QED

Sorry guys, I've been at this for quite awhile now..

Comment: What do you mean when you write "$\ldots$ then $x \in A - D$ and $x \in C - B$?" What is $x$?

Comment: If you are asked to prove $(A\subset B$ and $C\subset D)\Rightarrow (A-D\subset B-C)$ you should start with the hypothesis as your hypothesis and try to prove the conclusion.  *Suppose that $A\subset B$ and $C\subset D$.  Then...Then...So finally that means that $A-D\subset B-C$.*  Do not start with the conclusion and try to prove the hypothesis.

Comment: @Théophile x is an element in the set (A-D) and x is also an element in C-B

Comment: Its worth mentioning that the converse of this statement is false.  For counterexample let $A=B=D=\emptyset$ and $C=\{1\}$.  You have then that $C\not\subseteq D$ despite $A-D\subseteq B-C$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Can I say that Assume that (hypothesis), then Let x ... . Like how you said it in the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try and help you gain a bit of insight in what is going on here, the solution to this problem is about monotonicity, specifically, the monotonicity of $\;\land\;$ over $\;\Rightarrow\;$.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

We can start at the most complex side, the conclusion, and try to reach the other side, the assumptions:
$$\calc
    A - D \;\subseteq\; B - C
\op=\hints{definitions of $\;-\;$ and $\;\subseteq\;$}
    \hint{-- to go from the set theory level to the logic level}
    \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \not\in D \;\then\; x \in B \land x \not\in C \rangle
\op{\tag{*} \when}\hints{logic: monotonicity of $\;\land\;$ over $\;\then\;$ $\ref 0$, twice}
    \hint{-- this seems the only way to separate $\;A,B\;$ from $\;C,D\;$}
    \langle \forall x :: (x \in A \then x \in B) \;\land\; (x \not\in D \then x \not\in C) \rangle
\op=\hints{logic: split quantification into two parts}
    \hint{-- to bring $\;\land\;$ to the top level}
    \langle \forall x :: x \in A \then x \in B \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall x :: x \not\in D \then x \not\in C \rangle
\op=\hints{logic: contraposition in right hand side}
    \hint{-- to match the structure of the assumptions}
    \langle \forall x :: x \in A \then x \in B \rangle \;\land\; \langle \forall x :: x \in C \then x \in D \rangle
\op=\hint{definition of $\;\subseteq\;$, twice}
    A \subseteq B \;\land\; C \subseteq D
\endcalc$$

The key step is of course $\ref *$: this twice uses the fact that $\;\land\;$ is monotonic over $\;\then\;$, in both arguments:
\begin{align}
\tag{0a}
(P \then Q) \;\then\; (P \land R \;\then\; Q \land R)
\\
\tag{0b}
(P \then Q) \;\then\; (R \land P \;\then\; R \land Q)
\end{align}
(These two are of course equivalent.)

At the set theory level, we say that $\;-\;$ is monotonic over $\;\subseteq\;$ in its first argument, and anti-monotonic over $\;\subseteq\;$ in its second argument.  Combining these two results in this question's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Generally for proofs like this, you want to take an arbitrary element of the LHS and show that it must necessarily be an element of the RHS as well.

---

Suppose for hypothesis that $A\subseteq B$ and $C\subseteq D$.

Let $x\in A-D$.

This means that $x\in A$ and $x\notin D$.

Since $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq B$, this means that $x\in B$.

Also, since $x\notin D$ and $C\subseteq D$, this means $x\notin C$.

...

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot claim

> Since $A - D \subseteq B- C$...

The above is what you are trying to prove. You have to first suppose that $A, B, C, D $ are sets, and that $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq D$. Then show that with the given assumptions you have made, that $A - D \subseteq B- C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subset B$ and $C\subset D$,$\forall x [x\in A-D\implies (x\in A\land x\not \in D)\implies (x\in B\land x\not \in D)\implies (x\in B\land x\not \in D\cap C)\implies (x\in B\land x\not \in C)\implies (x\in B-C)].$

Comment: It often helps to draw a picture. Let B and D be partly overlapping discs.  Draw a line that cuts thru both discs.Let A be the part of B below the line. Let C be the part of D below the line.  Shade in A-D .Then shade in B-C.